# How to get an event from the application when the system theme changes?

Tags: uno-platform

Because the Theme Qualifier for iOS assets is not yet supported on Uno, I have to resort to a helper service in my project, to provide alternate paths to image which are created for dark mode. This however causes the assets URL to be evaluated once, and not when the system theme is changed while the app is running. Is there a way to get an event or method being called from the application when the system theme changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, you can also use the `UISettings.ColorValuesChanged` event to observe theme changes. Furthermore, Microsoft Community Toolkit provides a very nice wrapper around it - [`ThemeListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/themelistener), which can also be used in Uno Platform apps.

Ideally, we would also like to support the theme qualifier for asset disambiguation - similarly to `-scale-150`, etc. it allows you to use a suffix to let the system choose light or dark assets. You can upvote [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2197) to help us prioritize that.

Comment: I know, I reported that issue, and worked on it, but it stalled around the iOS implementation.

Comment: I marked your response as answer, since it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some UI assets to change based on theme, you can use [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension) with [ThemeDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.themedictionaries?view=winrt-22000).

### Example in an Uno project

#### Declaration of the theme resource in the theme dictionary

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="using:Uno.Gallery.Views.Styles.Application">
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <!-- Light Theme -->
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <x:String x:Key="UnoLogoImageSource">ms-appx:///Assets/UnoGalleryLogo_Light.png</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <!-- Dark Theme -->
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <x:String x:Key="UnoLogoImageSource">ms-appx:///Assets/UnoGalleryLogo_Dark.png</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Reference code:
https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Gallery/blob/master/Uno.Gallery/Uno.Gallery.UWP/Views/Colors.xaml#L11

#### Usage in a page

```xml
<Image Source="{ThemeResource UnoLogoImageSource}" />
```

Reference code: https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Gallery/blob/45e490668890c3a9db1e28a5b3de2a61822b07ca/Uno.Gallery/Uno.Gallery.UWP/Views/Shell.xaml#L45

Comment: Oh Wow, thats even better. Thanks for this!